# Server side caching of PHP readfile images

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, caching

For SEO reasons I am sending some images using PHP `readfile` and URL `rewrite`. I save images in a folder with numerical id `(id.jpg)` but serve the image with keywords (`some-seo-word-id.jpg`). While the scripts runs smoothly and show images effectively, however in pages with multiple images (5 to 6) it fails to send all images correctly.

Refreshing the pages 2 to 3 times sometimes shows all images, sometimes it does not ! Since the max image size delivered using PHP `readfile` is 70-140 KB each I highly doubt that memory can be an issue. My question is

1. Is there any better approach to this only with Apache `rewrite`.
2. How does Facebook deliver all images effectively with php ? There url are something like this `https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=XXXXXXXXX27&set=a.4533609xxxx.xxxx099.xxxx210426&type=1&theater`
3. will server side caching in binary format help ? To me this should not affect much as `readfile` of an image or cached file will still read a particular file (cached file instead of image !)

Comment: Why don't you save image as *some-seo-word-id.jpg* and let http caching on your http server?

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php and in other subject Facebok displays all the images through php to ensure security checking for permissions on the image

Comment: Because then I won't be able to use the same image somewhere else ! `some-seo-word.jpg` is content specific and same image can be used with different seo results .